# Need help mapping values in a 9x9 array divided into 3x3 sections

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 9x9 main array filled with integer values and I want to divide this main array into 9 3x3 sections and have a different array created for each section with an id that goes from 0 to 8. Furthermore, I want to have a list containing all 3x3 arrays so that I can access whichever I want with just their id.

Let's say I have this:

```
main_grid = np.array(some_9x9_array, dtype=int)
grid_sections = []
for _ in range(9):
    grid_sections.append(np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int))
```

And this is my some_9x9_array:

```
[ [3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 9, 0, 0, 5], 
  [0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 6, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
  [6, 0, 7, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3], 
  [9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0], 
  [0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0], ]
```

So the first 3x3 grid will contain the intersection of the rows 0, 1, 2 with the columns 0, 1, 2,
the second one the intersection of the rows 0, 1, 2 with the columns 3, 4, 5 and so on. The problem that I've come across is that for example the number at index (2, 3) in the main grid is 7
so I want the number at index (2, 0) of the second 3x3 section to be a 7. Another example is that number 6 at (4, 0) of the 9x9 grid should be at index (2, 0) of the third 3x3 section. I haven't figured out a way to do this any other way that using a lot of if statements to get the id of the 3x3 section that the number is in:

```
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        if i < 3:
            if j < 3:
                id = 0
            elif j < 6:
                id = 3
            else:
                id = 6
        elif i < 6:
            if j < 3:
                id = 1
            elif j < 6:
                id = 4
            else:
                id = 7
        else:
            if j < 3:
                id = 2
            elif j < 6:
                id = 5
            else:
                id = 8
```

With this I can get the id, however I still need to convert the index (2, 3) of the main grid
into index (2, 0) of the second 3x3 block so I can assign the same value to both positions.
Does anyone know a way to achieve this and a better approach for figuring out the section id that a number is in that doesn't involve all those if's statements?

Comment: I would suggest making a `Grid` class that holds a 3x3 int list. Then make a 3x3 `Grid` object list called `sections`

Comment: `id = (j // 3) * 3 + (i // 3)`

Comment: Index `(i, j)` in the main array is `(i % 3, j % 3)` in the subarray.

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I have thought that option but I would have to refactor the code I've already written but thanks for bringing it up, I will consider it

Comment: @MichaelButscher It worked, thank you. I always forget about the % operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by @MichaelButscher, section id:

```
section_id = (j // 3) * 3 + (i // 3)
```

And for the subarrays:

```
(i, j) in main array is (i % 3, j % 3) in subarray
```